# Frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make the desired output as shown in the picture? Frame 3 should be just beside to the two frames 1 and 2 regardless of how many widgets are inside them.

[image]

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Risk Calculator")
master.geometry("400x400")

group_1 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Frame 1")
group_1.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=8,pady=10,sticky="WE")

capital_label = tk.Label(group_1, text = 'Capital *', font=('calibre', 10))
capital_label.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky = 'e')

group_2 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Frame 2")
group_2.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=8,pady=4,sticky="WE")

broker_label = tk.Label(group_2, text = 'Broker', font=('calibre', 10))
broker_label.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=3,sticky='w')

group_3 = tk.LabelFrame(master, text="Frame 3")
group_3.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=8,pady=10,sticky="WE")

test = tk.Label(group_3, text = 'Test', font=('calibre', 10)) 
test.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=3,sticky='w')

test1 = tk.Label(group_3, text = 'Test1', font=('calibre', 10)) 
test1.grid(column=0,row=4,padx=3,sticky='w')

test2 = tk.Label(group_3, text = 'Test2', font=('calibre', 10)) 
test2.grid(column=0,row=5,padx=3,sticky='w')

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: For frames 1 and 2, add the argument `sticky=N` to the `.grid()` method. For frame 3, add the argument `rowspan=2` to the `.grid()` method.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please have a look at the [How to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

@Martin suggestion is good but it continues leaving an undesired white space between frame 1 and 2. You can use `pack` to perfectly control the output:

```
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Risk Calculator")
master.geometry("400x400")

# Frame Left
frame_left = tk.Frame(master)
frame_left.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)

# Frame right
frame_right = tk.Frame(master)
frame_right.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)


# Frame 1
group_1 = tk.LabelFrame(frame_left, text="Frame 1")
group_1.pack(padx=8, pady=10)

capital_label = tk.Label(group_1, text = 'Capital *', font=('calibre', 10))
capital_label.grid(column=0,row=1, sticky = 'e')

# Frame 2
group_2 = tk.LabelFrame(frame_left, text="Frame 2")
group_2.pack(padx=8,pady=4)

broker_label = tk.Label(group_2, text = 'Broker', font=('calibre', 10))
broker_label.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=3,sticky='w')

# Frame 3
group_3 = tk.LabelFrame(frame_right, text="Frame 3")
group_3.pack(padx=8, pady=10)

test = tk.Label(group_3, text = 'Test', font=('calibre', 10)) 
test.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=3,sticky='w')

test1 = tk.Label(group_3, text = 'Test1', font=('calibre', 10)) 
test1.grid(column=0,row=4,padx=3,sticky='w')

test2 = tk.Label(group_3, text = 'Test2', font=('calibre', 10)) 
test2.grid(column=0,row=5,padx=3,sticky='w')

master.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! will do in complete code. thanks so much @David!
thanks as well to @Martin!